How to get list of all android application room databases used in a single application
My current android application has a use case where I need to clear all tables in all the room databases employed within the application.
my android application has multiple feature modules and each feature module owns a room database to hold and manage the features local data.
my android application employs Koin to provide DI and I have solved the issue as shown below, I am concerned about how "future proof" this approach is a new feature modules are added with their own room database, its dependent on my colleagues declaring the koin room databases correctly.
    private var clearAllTablesJob: Job? = null
    private val roomLocalDatabases: List<RoomDatabase> = getKoin().getAll()
...
...
...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        clearAllTablesJob?.cancel()
        clearAllTablesJob = launch(Dispatchers.IO) { roomLocalDatabases.forEach { database -> database.clearAllTables() } }
    }

within koin I declare each database as follows:-
object MyKoinModule {
    val ioc = module {
        single { MyRoomDatabase.createDatabase(androidContext()) } bind RoomDatabase::class
    }
}

is this a "Heavy Handed" approach?
is there a "Better way" to solve this issue?
